# How to have meaningful transition on front end when REST API takes too much time to respond

Tags: web-services, rest

I want to build two web pages . On first page , it has one input field where I will upload CSV file. On the next page there is some other general information being shown.

Now my question is , if my CSV file is too large, it will take too much time to upload the data and put those entries into database successfully. During that time , I can't make user wait for that single successful response.

So what should be the ideal way where user can upload file (no matter how big the file is) on first page and move to the next page smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this seams to be the perfect case for an asynchronous task or even a new thread.

I mean, the user choose the file to upload, you get it in the webservice and launch a asyncronous thread with the process for that file.
In the meantime you send the user to the other page so that he can continue whatever he is doing.

But doing that, i don't know how you will be able to notify the user that the upload is success except if you check sometimes during the user experience.

I'm not experienced in thread so i might be wrong but this seams a good point to start for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions:

**First solution:**
I would recommend a PWA (Progressive Web App) solution to this. Instead of sending the user to another *web page*, by definition, you simply transition into another view. This would require client-side rendering, meaning no views sent from the server. The server’s only job in this case is to fetch, process and send back data to the client. The client on the other hand already has all views and can transition/switch between them seamlessly, not depending on the server, and simply asks for data from the server.

This is the solution I would do, but maybe you web service/app is completely different from this approach, and would require a major remake.

**Second solution:**
Consider using Service Workers. You could have a Service Worker working in the background, even if you send the user to another web page. When the server then asynchronously sends its response, the Service Worker is ready and can update the page dynamically.

Maybe this would be a more suitable solution in your case, depending on the current structure of your web service/application.